# Monad transformer flatMap working

Tags: scala, monads, scalaz, monad-transformers, scala-cats

I´ve been playing monad transformer, and I just create one Future[Option]. But after read some blogs there´s something that is not explained and I don't understand.

Here in the implementation of my `map` and `flatMap`, in the `flatMap` once that I get the value of my option, and I apply the function over the value, I have to invoke over the function `f(a)` the .`Value_passed_in_the_case_class(in this case future)`

```
case class FutOpt[A](future: Future[Option[A]]) {

def map[B](f: A => B): FutOpt[B] = {
  FutOpt(future.map(option => option.map(value => f(value)))
    .recoverWith {
      case e: Exception =>
        Future.successful(Option.empty)
    })
}

def flatMap[B](f: A => FutOpt[B]): FutOpt[B] =
  FutOpt(future.flatMap(option => option match {
    case Some(a) => f(a).future  --> WHAT THIS .future IS DOING?
    case None => Future.successful(None)
  }))
}
```

What is happening there?, and how works?.

Regards.

Comment: `.future` is just accessing the field you defined in `case class FutOpt[A](future: Future[Option[A]])`

Comment: yes I get that, but why needs to access that field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is happening there?

`flatMap` expects you to return it a `FutOpt[B]`:

```
def flatMap[B](f: A => FutOpt[B]): FutOpt[B]
```

The signature of your case class requires you to pass in a `Future[Option[A]]`:

```
case class FutOpt[A](future: Future[Option[A]])
```

This line of code:

```
FutOpt(future.flatMap(option => option match {
    case Some(a) => f(a).future
```

Is constructing a new instance of `FutOpt[B]`, and it *needs* a value of type `Future[Option[B]]` in order to be able to construct itself properly. `f(a)` returns a `FutOpt[B]`, not a `Future[Option[B]]`, and that is why it needs to access `.future`, which is of type `Future[Option[B]]`.

Comment: Correct jesus I was so blind!!